Properties of Kronecker sum for matrix pencils
Given two square matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and their Kronecker sum defined as
$ A\oplus B =I_m\otimes A+B\otimes I_n$,
It is the known that the eigenstructure of $A\oplus B$ is completely characterized by that of $A$ and $B$.
I am wondering is there any similar properties for a regular matrix pencil $A+\lambda B$. Specifically, is there any relation between the eigenvalues of $A+\lambda B$ and $A\oplus A+\lambda B\oplus B$? Keep in mind that the eigenvalues of a matrix pencil is defined as $\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}:{\rm det}(A+\lambda B)=0 \}$.
